# Prevent Redactor from adding site identifier to entry links

Tags: redactor, reference-tags

I have a multi-site setup, and when using Redactor's **Link to an entry** function, by default, site identifiers are added to the link href:

`href="https://mysite/my-page#entry:4223@3:url"`

I would like to prevent (or strip out) the `@3` site identifier, because I wish to use the current site's base URL, rather than specify a specific site's base URL be used. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a [Redactor plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor#redactor-js-plugins) that listens for the [`link.inserted`](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/link/) event and strips out the site identifer:

`craft/config/redactor/plugins/myplugin.js`:

```
(function($R)
{
    $R.add('plugin', 'myplugin', {
        onlink: {
            inserted: function(link) { 
                link.nodes.forEach(node => node.href = node.href.replace(/@\d+/, ''))
             },
        },
    });
})(Redactor);
```

`craft/config/redactor/redactorFieldConfig.json`:

```
{
    "plugins": ["myplugin"]
}
```